# Tie External Username/Password to iPhone and iPad device

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, credentials

I have data that is usually printed out and purchased face to face.  Id like to have this data available via the iphone/ipad now, but cant share it between other iphone/ipads.  Is there a way to tie an external applications username/password to a persons' devices? I'm not sure this is possible.

Comment: you may need to be more specific. Is the data stored on a server or on the users device?

Comment: This for the enterprise? Sounds like a possibility. In that case you should look at integrating with MDMs to manage users, devices, and what data is sent

Comment: This data is stored on a server.  What is MDM?  The more I was thinking do I have access to their Apple account on the device?